# How to update to Nautilus 3.18.2 in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: nautilus

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm still exploring it's features, so could someone help me how to upgrade Nautilus 3.16 to 3.18.2. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or Ubuntu GNOME?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can`t get the version 3.18 on Willy from [Gnome3 official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3). But you can have the version 3.16:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Note:** Only if you have the Ubuntu Xenial you get the version 3.18